# How to pass values from foreach to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I loop values in controller send it to view in CodeIgniter

I have tried with below code

**Controller**

```
 public function getdata()
 {
    $data =  $this->Mdi_download_invoices->download_pdf_files(12);       
    foreach ($data as $d)   
        {
             $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
             $html = $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$d,true);
             $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
             $mpdf->Output($estructure.$d->invoice_id,'F');
        }
 }
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo $d->invoice_id;
    ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But data is not printing in the view.How can I print the values??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can't `foreach` and pass the data to view.

```
 public function getdata()
 {
    $result =  $this->Mdi_download_invoices->download_pdf_files(12);       
    $data['d'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$data);
 }
```

> **Note:** Since you're using `echo $d->invoice_id;` check whether your [**result object**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) (`row`, `result`)

Comment: hello Abdulla, Actually my problem is I have to generate separate pdf file for each record.I have updated my question can u please take a look.

Comment: `foreach` it in view

Comment: But will it generate multiple pdf files at once if I use foreach in view??

Comment: why don't you try it even ?? whats inside   `$result` ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this :

```
<?php 
     public function getdata()
     {
        $data =  $this->Mdi_download_invoices->download_pdf_files(12);       
        foreach ($data as $d)   
            {
                $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
                $html = $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$d,true);
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                $mpdf->Output($estructure.$d->invoice_id,'F');

                $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$d);
            }
     }

?>
```